# Wait at most N seconds for a fork'd child PID to finish

Tags: python, multithreading, fork

I'm trying to use `os.fork`, `os.waitpid`, and threading to dispatch some time-consuming work to a child process, wait **at most** a certain amount of time for it to complete, and then continue on, leaving it running in the background. There is also a secondary timer in the child that prevents it from running for too long in the background, like so:

```
Fork execution
In the fork's child:
    Start a thread to execute a task
        If that thread runs for longer than X milliseconds:
             thread.stop(), a custom method that softly stops the thread.
In the fork's parent:
    If the child's PID stays running for longer than Y milliseconds:
        return -1
    else:
        return 0
```

After returning a value, I want the script to terminate. The child can and should keep running if it isn't done.

The code I have tried (abbreviated) is:

```
class MyCustomThread(threading.Thread):
    abort = False
    def run(self):
        counter = 0
        while True:
            if self.abort: break
            counter += 1
            if counter == 30: self.stop()
            sleep(1)
        return 0

    def stop(self):
        self.abort = True

def test():
    X = 2000
    Y = 500
    pid = os.fork()
    if pid == 0:
        thread1 = MyCustomThread() #Sleeps for 30 seconds and ends.
        thread1.start()
        print "Started 1!"
        timeout = X # say, 1000ms
        while timeout > 0:
            if not thread1.is_alive(): return "custom thread finished before the deadline!"
            timeout -= 1
            sleep(0.001)
        if thread1.is_alive():
            return "custom thread didn't finish before the deadline!"
            thread1.stop()
        exit()
    else:
        print pid
        thread2 = Thread(target = os.waitpid, args = (pid, 0))
        thread2.start()
        print "Started 2!"
        timeout2 = Y # say, 500ms
        while timeout2 > 0:
            if not thread2.is_alive(): return "child PID finished!"
            timeout2 -= 1
            sleep(0.001)
        if thread2.is_alive():
            return "child PID didn't finish yet!"
print test()
print "all done!"
```

The output is correct, in that I get

```
1171
Started 2!
Started 1!
child PID didn't finish yet!
all done!
custom thread didn't finish before the deadline!
all done!
```

But then the script doesn't exit! It sleeps for the remaining 28 seconds before

**How do I make the main execution of this script complete after the `fork`ed parent returns a value?** As I said before, the child can and should keep running in the background, it just shouldn't block execution of the next task on the parent.

I really don't even care if the child can print output to standard out--in the actual implementation, all it's doing is talking to a database, so it doesn't need to report anything interactively. The parent, however, needs to dispatch the child, wait **at most** Y seconds for the child to finish, and then (as far as whoever invoked the script is concerned) end the script's execution so that the next thing can be done. The other timer (X) isn't relevant, I think; it only exists to keep the child from running too long in the background.

Any ideas? I'm probably approaching this totally wrong, so "start over and do it *_* way" ideas are welcome.

Comment: A [`threading.Thread`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/threading.html#thread-objects) object doesn't have a pre-defined `stop` method. Where does the `stop` method come from, and what's in it? I think we need to know to answer this question.

Comment: Added an example class. The real one is considerably longer, but doesn't do anything particularly unique (no other threads or subprocesses or whatnot). The one I added sleeps for 30 seconds, nothing more. The goal, however, is for the program to take AT MOST Y milliseconds to run. Whatever the deadline and stop() behavior is, it should take place in the background.

Comment: Why do you need to start a thread in the child? Just set an alarm, install a signal handler for SIGALRM with a simple exit(0). Then do your work in the child process. When the timer expires, the child process will receive SIGALRM and will exit. In the parent you can install a signal handler for SIGCHLD (when the child exits the kernel will invoke the parent process' signal handler).

Comment: @SvenMarnach, yeah, I realised that and deleted the comment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out, thanks for all the pointers!
**Edit:** fixed `is_pid_alive` function to work if called from within a child as well.

The issue was that the parent's "watcher" thread was never completing, since `os.waitpid` isn't a pollable/loopable function. The solution was to remove the "watcher" thread, and instead implement a polling loop that checks a `pid_is_alive()` function every millisecond, like so:

```
def pid_is_alive(pid):
    try:
        os.kill(pid, 0)
        os.waitpid(pid, os.WNOHANG)
        os.kill(pid, 0)
    except OSError:
        return False
    return True


def test():
    X = 1000 * 1000
    Y = 5000
    pid = os.fork()
    if pid == 0:
        thread1 =  MyCustomThread() #Sleeps for 30 seconds and ends.
        thread1.start()
        print "Started 1!"
        timeout = X # say, 1000ms
        while timeout > 0:
            if not thread1.is_alive(): return "custom thread finished before the deadline!"
            timeout -= 1
            sleep(0.001)
        if thread1.is_alive():
            return "custom thread didn't finish before the deadline!"
            thread1.stop()
        exit()

    else:
        timeout2 = Y # say, 500ms
        while timeout2 > 0:
            if not pid_is_alive(pid): return "child PID finished!"
            timeout2 -= 1
            sleep(0.001)
        if pid_is_alive(pid):
            print "child PID didn't finish yet!"
            exit()
print test()
print "all done!"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this one, it doesn't use threading, just pure fork/waitpid/alarm/sighandler:

```
child_exited = False

def sigh(signum, frame):
    global child_exited
    if signum == signal.SIGALRM:
        print "custom thread didn't finish before the deadline!"
        #forced exit:
        exit(1)     

    if signum == signal.SIGCHLD:
        (pid, status) = os.waitpid(-1, 0) 
        print "child exited with status: " + str(os.WEXITSTATUS(status))
        child_exited = True

def test():
    global child_exited
    pid = os.fork()
    if pid == 0:
        signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, sigh)
        signal.alarm(30)

        #do work:
        print "Started 1"
        time.sleep(60)

        #clean exit:
        exit(0)
    elif (pid > 0):
        signal.signal(signal.SIGCHLD, sigh)
        print "Started 2"
        #this sleep will return prematurely if the child exits
        time.sleep(10)

        if not child_exited:
          print "child PID didn't finish yet!"
    else:
        print "fork() failed"

print test()
print "all done!"
```

Comment: I considered accepting this answer, but decided in favor of the one I discovered due to the unintuitive behavior of `alarm`. Since `alarm` is effectively a global that cannot be read, just written, I tend to avoid using it in programs containing code I don't control (such as this one). Unless you have a runtime that both a) abstracts the single-timer nature of `alarm` away inside a function and b) you can be reasonably sure isn't linking any external code that does not obey that abstraction, I would suggest avoiding `alarm`. Upvoted though! Thanks!

Comment: For Python3 you need to call `interrupt_main()` at the end of the `signal.SIGCHLD` signal handler, otherwise the `time.sleep()` is not interrupted. Calling `interrupt_main()` for Python2 too does not hurt either. You need to add `try ... except KeyboardInterrupt: pass` around the `time.sleep()`
`interrupt_main()` can be made available so:
`if sys.version_info[0] < 3: 
  from thread import interrupt_main
else:
  from _thread import interrupt_main`

Answer (score 1):

This is not an exact answer to your question, but rather a "start over and do it _ way" idea.

You could use the `multiprocessing` module.  The function [`Pool.apply_async()`](http://docs.python.org//library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.apply_async) allows to execute a function in the background, and the returned [`AsyncResult`](http://docs.python.org//library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.AsyncResult) object features [`wait()`](http://docs.python.org//library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.AsyncResult.wait) and [`get()`](http://docs.python.org//library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.AsyncResult.get) methods with a `timeout` parameter.

Your code would essentially become (untested)

```
import multiprocessing

def computationally_intensive():
    # whatever

p = multiprocessing.Pool(1)
deferred = p.apply_async(computationally_intensive)
try:
    result = deferred.get(10)              # 10 being the timeout
except multiprocessing.TimeoutError:
    # Handle time out
# ...
p.terminate()
```

Comment: Good idea, but I need the equivalent of `computationally_intensive` to continue running in a separate Unix process even if the master terminates completely.

Comment: @ZacB: Why?  Just keep the master alive, doing nothing.  I can't see any reason why this shouldn't be an option.  You can also daemonise it, so the user doesn't even notice it's still running unless she checks the process list.

Comment: Constraints of an embedded environment, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

you may use `join` method of Thread

```
thread2.join(timeout=Y)
if not thread2.is_alive():
   # TODO: Post Processing
```